# Vuex commit not updating state

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am creating a language flashcard app and am having issues with the state updating when I switch lists. So I see that in my store the mutations are being fired but in my Vuex Dev Tools the state is not registering a change despite the vue updating somewhat...

HTML

```
<label style="margin-left: 5px">Word List</label>
<md-select id="list-select" v-model="currentList">
   <md-option v-for="(list, index) in wordLists" :key="index" :value="list.id">
       {{list.name}}
   </md-option>
</md-select>
```

JS Component

```
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';

...

computed: {
  ...mapGetters({
     showModalState: 'showModal',
     computedList: 'currentListWords',
     wordLists: 'wordLists'
  }),

...

watch: {
  currentList(val) {
     let list = this.wordLists.filter((v) => v.id === val).slice();

      this.$store.commit("setCurrentList", list);
      this.$store.commit("setTempList", list);
  }

...
```

JS Store Mutations

```
setCurrentList(state, payload){
  state.currentList = payload;
},
setTempList(state, payload){
  state.tempList = payload;
},
```

JS Getters

```
wordLists(state){
  return state.wordList;
},
currentList(state){
  return state.currentList;
},
```

STORE

```
...
currentList: [],
wordLists: [],
...
```

Comment: Is state.currentList an object?? Id so then you will have to use Vue.set or Object.assign

Comment: It is an object in an array...

Comment: Did you describe your properties in initial vuex state?
{ state: () => ({ currentList: [], tempList: [] }) }

Also i think you have mistake in properties name

Answer (score 1):

For making the changes reactive you cannot directly assign the values. You will need to use Vue.set(If value of particular attribute/index is to be updated) or Object.assign (if complete object is being updated). Learn more about vue reactivity [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats).

You will have to do as below in mutation to make your changes reactive.

```
state.currentList = Object.assign({}, state.currentList, payload)

state.tempList = Object.assign({}, state.tempList, payload)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `getters` in your Vuex store object? `store.getters.showModal`, `store.getters.currentListWords` etc. If not, use `mapState` instead of `mapGetters` to access plain state.

Comment: Ah sorry I forgot to add that part in. I did. Let me edit now!